# C++ Convert pointer from one derived class to another

Tags: c++, inheritance

Say i have a class shape and 2 derived classes circle and square. The code is:

```
Shape* s1 = new circle;
```

Now I want to asssigne s1 to square, while preserving the variables that are common to both.

```
Shape* s1 = new Square;
```

How do i do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "preserving the variables"?

Comment: I think he means "members". It's not possible without using a conversion function. And why do you want to convert a circle to a square ?

Comment: You **don't** do that. "How" is irrelevant.

Comment: when is say preserve variables i mean like say shape has a protected variable "side" which is inherited. When i convert circle to square, square->size must be equal to what circle->size was. The circle, square thing is just a trivial example i'm using. I don't convert circles to squares :P
EDIT: All variables in square and circle are inherited. They don't have unique variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a constructor that takes a reference to the base class, you can easily copy the common `Shape` data:

```
#include <assert.h>

enum class Color { red, green, blue };

class Shape {
  public:
    Shape() : color(red) { }
    void setColor(Color new_color) { color = new_color; }
    Color getColor() const { return color; }
  private:
    Color color;
};

class Square : public Shape {
  public:
    Square() { }
    // Using explicit constructor to help avoid accidentally
    // using the wrong type of shape.
    explicit Square(const Shape &that) : Shape(that) { }
};

class Circle : public Shape {
  public:
    Circle() { }
    explicit Circle(const Shape &that) : Shape(that) { }
};

int main(int,char**)
{
  Circle circle;
  circle.setColor(Color::blue);
  Square square(circle);
  assert(circle.getColor()==square.getColor());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your copy constructor :

```
Shape* s1 = new Circle;
Shape* s1 = new Square( s1 );
```

With :

```
class Square : public Shape
{
    ...
public:
    Square( const Circle& rhs )
    {
        // Copy the value you want to keep
        // Respect the rules of copy constructor implementation
    }
    // Even better :
    Square( const Shape& rhs )
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
};
```

Don't forget that converting a Circle into Square is a bit weird.

And there is a **memory LEAK** in your implementation. If you don't want to use you `Circle`, delete it.

This would be better :

```
Shape* s1 = new Circle;
Shape* s2 = new Square( s1 );

delete s1;
```

EDIT : Here is a link about copy constructor and assignement operator : http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/